# How do I reorder variables in a Sas dataset in a specific sequence when merging?

Tags: sas

Example:

I need to reorder variables in a dataset consisting of 3 datasets merged together.

```
Dataset1: test_1 test_2 test_3 test_4... test_n
Dataset2: plu_1 plu_2 plu_3 plu_4... plu_n
Dataset3: set_1 set_2 set_3 set_4... set_n
```

I need one dataset with variables reordered to this: `test1 plu1 set1 test2 plu2 set2...test_n plu_n set_n`

I have several hundred variables so manually writing the ordering in e.g. a retain statement wont do it.

Answer (score 1):

There are no sample datasets, but you could try this way:
1. Get variables of dataset by proc contents;
2. Sort name;
3. Set dummy variable for merge;
4. Save variables sequence to a macro variable;
5. merge your three datasets,put retain before merge.

```
%macro varslist(dsn);
    proc contents data=&dsn out=&dsn._&dsn(keep=name);
    proc sort data=&dsn._&dsn;
    by name;
    data &dsn._&dsn;
       set &dsn._&dsn;
       rename name=name_&dsn;
       dummy=_n_;
    run;
%mend;

%varslist(dataset1)
%varslist(dataset2)
%varslist(dataset3)


data _null_;
   merge dataset1_dataset1 dataset2_dataset2  dataset3_dataset3 end=last;
   by dummy;
   length list $2000.;
   retain list;
   list=catx(' ',list,of name:);
   if last then call symputx('namelist',list);
run;

data want;
   retain &namelist;
   merge dataset1 dataset2 dataset3;
   by var;
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution assumes that all 3 datasets have the same number of columns, in the same order (I don't know if you have an id column to merge on, if so then the code will need tweaking slightly).

I'm taking advantage of the metadata table `dictionary.columns` (`sashelp.vcolumn` is the view for this), which stores the position of each column in any given dataset.  E.g. test_1, plu_1, set_1 will all have position 1, test_2, plu_2, set_2 position 2 etc.  You can therefore extract the names and position from all 3 datasets, then sort by position to give you the required order for the merged dataset.  It's then a simple matter of storing these names in a macro list, to be used in a `retain` statement prior to the `merge` statement.

The code is below.  I initially included an `order by` statement to the first sql block, but strangely it didn't order the data consistently (it highlighted the fact that `proc sql` doesn't read in the data sequentially, unlike a data step).  Omitting the `order by` and adding a subsequent `proc sort` fixed the issue.

```
/* set up dummy datasets */
data have1;
retain test_1 test_2 test_3 0;
run;

data have2;
retain plu_1 plu_2 plu_3 0;
run;

data have3;
retain set_1 set_2 set_3 0;
run;

/* pull out column names and position from dictionary data */
proc sql;
create table temp as select name, varnum
from dictionary.columns
where upper(libname) = 'WORK' and upper(memname) in ('HAVE1','HAVE2','HAVE3');
quit;

/* sort by column position */
proc sort data=temp;
by varnum;
run;

/* put sorted column names into macro list */
proc sql noprint;
select name into :vars separated by ' '
from temp;
quit;

%put varlist = &vars.;

/* merge data with columns in correct position */
data want;
retain &vars.;
merge have1 have2 have3;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

To interleave the 3 lists of variables like this without hard-coding anything you will need to generate your preferred re-ordering statement (I prefer `informat` rather than `retain` as it causes fewer changes to data step behaviour) via either a macro, or a data step using call execute.

Please note that this site is not a code on demand service, so please have a go at implementing this yourself, and post back here if you have any problems with a specific part of it.

Answer (score 0):

For a one-time deal where you know what your number of "variable triplets" is, this is fast and easy:

```
%macro MERGEM(VARCOUNT=30);

    data OUT ;
    retain KEY 
    %do I=1 %to &VARCOUNT;
       test_&I plu_&I set_&I 
    %end;  ;
    merge DATASET1
          DATASET2
          DATASET3 ;
    by KEY ;
    run;

%mend MERGEM;

%MERGEM(VARCOUNT=30);
```

(Don't forget the 2nd ";"  following the %end ... the first closes the %do loop, and the second closes the retain statement.)